# WCF Rest service with Multiple Operation contract

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I want to Create WCF Rest service with Operation Contract Like this

```
public interface ICustomerService  
{  
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetAllCustomer/")]  
    List<CustomerDataContract> GetAllCustomer();  

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetSTOCK/ABC")]  
    List<CustomerDataContract> GetSTOCK();  

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,  
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GETSUPINFO/XYZ/ABC")]  
    List<CustomerDataContract> GETSUPINFO();   
}
```

Can Any one Help?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: We will be able to help you only if you tell us what help you need. Are you facing any errors/issues?

Comment: its wotking fine for Filst URI but for second and third End Point Not found

Comment: Why do you have /ABC & /XYZ/ABC in the GET api's? If you want to Pass values to GET api - then your UriTemplate is wrong and should be /{ABC}... Also add a parameter to the method of the relevant datatype for ABC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get your logic supported with Restful service protocol. The first one is to change your WCF service, you can refer to the following links for more details.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178(v=vs.90).aspx

More easier way is to wrap your logic with WepAPI, and just leave your WCF services as-is. You can also get more information from the following link about WebAPI.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx